# GAS and Google Sites...trouble with gadget

Tags: google-apps-script

Q1-I have a working google apps script for a spreadsheet.  I want to display the spreadsheet results on a Google Sites page.  Couldn't get my deployed script talking, so I tried a very simple one embedded in the Site:

```
function doGet() {
   return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello World');
}
```

Just get a blank in the gadget display box.  I'm set up as the owner, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Q2- I'd like the sites page to have 4 GAS gadgets on the same page.  Do the scripts/functions need to be broken out so each is tied to a *doGet()* ?

Q3- Is there a simpler service for creating a simple XML/dynamic table with the spreadsheet results?..or is *google Sites* the best approach?
Thanks in advance--

Nathan

Comment: On your Q3, it all depends on what you want to be doing with the spreadsheet. Are you just reading cells from a spreadsheet and displaying them in a table? Or are you creating a form to request specific spreadsheet results? Or are you doing some math on what's in the spreadsheet and then displaying that?

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I'm using the spreadsheet as a database.  All the math is done by the script.  So essentially it is just text.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: TextOutput is not an acceptable display for a Sites gadget. [Read about it here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets#which-scripts). Only HtmlOutput and UiInstance are acceptable.

Q2: If you're going to have 4 gadgets, you will need 4 projects each with its own `doGet(e)`. You can't have multiple `doGet(e)` functions in the same project.

Q3: To try to give you some options here. If you're using Google Sites just to display your script output, you don't need to do that. You can [publish scripts to the web](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps) so they run just like a webpage. In this web app, you can create multiple elements. See [charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_charts) where you can create a lot of different great visualizations for some data. Look into [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiapp) to understand how to add multiple elements to a UI.